# How to redact data from array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

If I have a weather data, which is an array, like this one below.

```
const weather = [
{date:'2022-07-18', min_temp:15, max_temp:26, type:'clouds'},
{date:'2022-07-18', min_temp:13, max_temp:27, type:'sun'},
{date:'2022-07-18', min_temp:23, max_temp:31, type:'clouds'},
{date:'2022-07-18', min_temp:19, max_temp:28, type:'rain'},

{date:'2022-07-19', min_temp:21, max_temp:25, type:'rain'},
{date:'2022-07-19', min_temp:17, max_temp:29, type:'rain'},
{date:'2022-07-19', min_temp:14, max_temp:38, type:'rain'},
{date:'2022-07-19', min_temp:9, max_temp:30, type:'clouds'}
]
```

How can I reduce the array, one data/date, with the min and max temperature from the same date, and type should be the most frequently type from the same date.
It should look like this one below.

```
const weather = [
{date:'2022-07-18', min_temp=13, max_temp31, type:'clouds'},
{date:'2022-07-19', min_temp=9, max_temp:38, type:'rain'}
]
```

Comment: In your second example for `2022-07-19`, how did you arrive at the result of `rain` for key `type`? What logic did you follow? Can you share your attempt as a [mre]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is first to group by date. This is done using the first reduce. While we do, we store the frequency of each type. and the min/max temp.
Then we take the values of this object as the required array. Only a little housekeeping removing the `freq` helper object. And setting the `type` to be indeed the most frequent (amongst that date).

```js
const weather = [
  {date:'2022-07-18', min_temp:15, max_temp:26, type:'clouds'},
  {date:'2022-07-18', min_temp:13, max_temp:27, type:'sun'},
  {date:'2022-07-18', min_temp:23, max_temp:31, type:'clouds'},
  {date:'2022-07-18', min_temp:19, max_temp:28, type:'rain'},
  {date:'2022-07-19', min_temp:21, max_temp:25, type:'rain'},
  {date:'2022-07-19', min_temp:17, max_temp:29, type:'rain'},
  {date:'2022-07-19', min_temp:14, max_temp:38, type:'rain'},
  {date:'2022-07-19', min_temp:9, max_temp:30, type:'clouds'}
];

var step1 = Object.values(weather.reduce(function(agg, item) {
  var {date, min_temp, max_temp, type} = item;
  if (agg[date]) {
    agg[date].min_temp = Math.min(agg[date].min_temp, min_temp)
    agg[date].max_temp = Math.max(agg[date].max_temp, max_temp)
  } else {
    agg[date] = item
    agg[date].freq = {}
  }
  agg[date].freq[type] = (agg[date].freq[type] || 0) + 1
  return agg;
}, {})).map(function(item) {
  var most_common = 0;
  Object.entries(item.freq).reduce(function(agg, [key, value]) {
    if (agg<value) {
      agg = value;
      most_common = key;
    }
  }, 0);
  delete item.freq;
  item.type = most_common;
  return item;
})
console.log(step1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reduce` to collect the values per date into a map, and then get the values of that map:

```js
const weathers = [
{date:'2022-07-18', min_temp:15, max_temp:26, type:'clouds'},
{date:'2022-07-18', min_temp:13, max_temp:27, type:'sun'},
{date:'2022-07-18', min_temp:23, max_temp:31, type:'clouds'},
{date:'2022-07-18', min_temp:19, max_temp:28, type:'rain'},
{date:'2022-07-19', min_temp:21, max_temp:25, type:'rain'},
{date:'2022-07-19', min_temp:17, max_temp:29, type:'rain'},
{date:'2022-07-19', min_temp:14, max_temp:38, type:'rain'},
{date:'2022-07-19', min_temp:9, max_temp:30, type:'clouds'}
]

const weatherByDate = weathers.reduce((acc, curr) => {
const date = curr.date
const weather = acc[date]

if (weather) {
    const copy = { ...weather }
    copy.min_temp = Math.min(curr.min_temp, weather.min_temp)
    copy.max_temp = Math.max(curr.max_temp, weather.max_temp)
    
    const count = (weather.typeCounts[curr.type] || 0) + 1
    copy.typeCounts[curr.type] = count
    
    if(count > weather.typeCounts.max) {
      copy.typeCounts.max = count
      copy.type = curr.type
    }
    
    acc[date] = copy
} else {
    acc[date] = { ...curr, typeCounts: { [curr.type]: 1, max: 1 } }
}

return acc
}, {})

const arr = Object.values(weatherByDate).map(({typeCounts, ...rest}) => rest)

console.log(arr)
```

EDIT: Edited to keep most frequent `type` per date